# Drupal: can I setup cron with absolute paths?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to setup cron on my ubuntu server. I have several Drupal websites (with different domains).

In the drupal.org help pages, it is suggested to use the domain http://www.example.com/cron.php

However, I was wondering what to do if I have multiple domains ? Should I add multiple lines for each website ??

Also, what happen if I'm hiding the website using a subdomain while development ? Isn't better to specify the Drupal absolute path on the server instead ?

Can I use instead:

> 0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 /var/www/drupal/cron.php

?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When to run**

Yes, you want to have one entry per line. Unless the output of errors or simliar are prefixed with what site they came from, you would have no way of knowing *what* site failed.

You should also offset when each sites cron.php is executed, this is more important if you have a larger number of sites.

**Trigger**

You can call `/var/www/drupal/cron.php` without the webserver, although you need to specify the path to PHP and have your script as the argument, not use `wget`. What this path is will differ depending on your system. Try `which php` in your shell to see where it is.

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

So, your crontab could end up looking like this:

```
0  * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/drupal/cron.php
30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/other_drupal_site/cron.php
```

The first one is started every *hh:00* and the second one *hh:30*.

It is mentioned in http://drupal.org/cron that you can execute the script locally, search for `/usr/bin/php` on the page to go there (didn't find an anchor).

Comment: Thanks. So I will use an offset of 5 minutes and if I have more than 12 websites, i will have multiple cron runs at the same minute.. is that ok ?

Comment: @Patrick Absolutley, it depends on your servers specs :-) Not sure about PHP, but I'd guess memory would be the first one to run out; but you would have to go WAY above 12 sites for that, even concurrently.

Comment: ok thanks. One last question: do I need to restart my webserver after I've edited crontab to add a new line ? Or do I need to reboot something else ? clean caches ?

Comment: @Patrick No. The webserver can be turned off (it is irrelevant, is what I mean), when you load/save a new crontab, it is active instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use drush instead. here's how to run drush for multi-site,

http://blog.thetajoin.com/content/drush-multisite-cron